# Need help to identify a piece - two 1x2 plates connected by curved lines

Tags: part-identification

Bought a used collection and got many of these [image: this piece] in different colors. Wasn't able to find a set containing similar pieces.

It looks like the top of a cockpit.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part [47755 Wedge 4x3 Open with Cutout and 4 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47755&name=Wedge%204%20x%203%20Open%20with%20Cutout%20and%204%20Studs&category=%5BWedge%5D#T=C).

[image]